# Store Email Address

Tags: magento-1.9, email

I have a really weird problem. I am pretty used to magento and pretty familiar with everything however I have never encountered this before.
I installed a fresh cop of Magento 1.9.2.4 in my siteground hosting.
Whenever I use the example@example.com (the default emails found in configureations/store email addresses) all my order email (with cron job) and invoice and ship email works.
However when I put in an email of mine (sales@mydomain.com), nothing works, order email, invoice email, contact us, ship notification email, etc... stops to work.

Comment: hey, what does not working mean. You don't receive the mails, you maybe get an error or are they not added to the mail queue?

Comment: Create simple php mail() function to send test email on your domain & check your email if it is still not working then you have to enable mail setting by your hosting support.

Answer (score 0):

## SMTP settings for Magento

If you want to **send emails with Magento** you need to configure it to use an **SMTP server** – that is, the outgoing server that takes care of delivering your messages.

Remember anyway that if you set a **normal SMTP server on Magento** – like the ones associated to Gmail or Hotmail – you could always run into deliverability problems. Only a **[professional SMTP service](/en/tsmtpregistration1.php)** will guarantee a full delivery rate, so if you plan to set up an email campaign you should consider this option seriously.

And here's the procedure:

**1.** Login to Magento and choose System->Configuration->Advanced->System->Mail Sending Settings.

**2.** Insert your SMTP settings: your SMTP server name (if you don't know it have a look at our [handy list of the major ones](/en/what-is-my-smtp)) and your SMTP port (the default one is 25, but you can [choose among others](/en/port-for-smtp) as well).

**3.** Copy in your local the file app/code/core/Mage/core/Model/Email/Template.php.

**4.** Enable that module.

**5.** Open the file Template.php and change the getMail() function this way:

public function getMail()   
      {
           if (is_null($this->_mail)) {               
﻿               /* changes begin */      
﻿             $my_smtp_host = Mage::getStoreConfig('system/smtp/host');
             $my_smtp_port = Mage::getStoreConfig('system/smtp/port');
             $﻿config = array(
                       ﻿'port' => $my_smtp_port,                                              'auth' => 'login',                   
                       'username' => 'email@domain.com', 
                       ﻿'password' => 'yourpassword'                                               );
            $transport = new Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp($my_smtp_host, $config);
            Zend_Mail::setDefaultTransport($transport);
            /* Changes End */
            $this->_mail = new Zend_Mail('utf-8');
        }
        return $this->_mail;  
﻿}﻿

That's it, you can deliver emails with Magento.

Also you may consider [this extension.](https://github.com/aschroder/Magento-SMTP-Pro-Email-Extension)